# Сортировка многомерного массива

Tags: битрикс, php

Добрый день!

Есть такой массив (привожу его часть):

```
[4] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 33
        [UF_NAME] => 29
        [UF_XML_ID] => 6ea9ab1baa0efb9e19094440c317e21b
        [PROP_KEY] => PROP_44
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 35
        [UF_NAME] => 31
        [UF_XML_ID] => c16a5320fa475530d9583c34fd356ef5
        [PROP_KEY] => PROP_44
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 34
        [UF_NAME] => 30
        [UF_XML_ID] => 34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f
        [PROP_KEY] => PROP_44
    )
```

Результат выборки из HL инфоблока 1С Битрикс (это список размеров одежды):

```
                /*Работа со справочниками*/
                $hlblock = HL\HighloadBlockTable::getById($HL_blockID)->fetch();
                $entity = HL\HighloadBlockTable::compileEntity($hlblock);
                $entity_data_class = $entity->getDataClass();

                $rsProdInDB = $entity_data_class::getList(array(
                     "order"=> Array('UF_NAME'=>'ASC'),
                     "select"=> Array('ID','UF_NAME','UF_XML_ID'),
                     "filter"=> Array('=ID' =>$treeElement),
                ));
```

Размером (т.е. то, что видит пользователь) тут является поле `UF_NAME`. Как видите, они идут не по порядку. Отсортировать их на этапе получения (т.е. пока работает `::GetList()`) не получается, там куча других свойств выбирается, в общем, долго объяснять. Вот я и пытаюсь отсортировать его уже после получения.

**Обновление**

Там вначале идёт перебор торговых предложений, у торговых предложений я получаю ID элементов HL инфоблока, потом по ним вытягиваю `"filter"=> Array('=ID' =>$treeElement)`, из HL инфоблока остальные данные элемента `'UF_NAME'` и `'UF_XML_ID'`. В общем, возможно, про руководство битрикса Вы правы. ))

Comment: Что мешает использовать функцию usort?

Comment: Наверное, руководство по 1с-bitrix. )

Comment: Отсортировать их на этапе получения  -  а это еще почему? Что может быть проще сортировки в момент выборки из БД?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. @iksuy, а поконкретнее?

Comment: Глянь [тут](http://max22.ru/d7/highload-about/) - я как понял, работа через построитель запроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из UF_NAME делаются ключи, в которые профтыкается все остальное (и UF_NAME тоже можно), и все автоматически окажется сортированным.

Comment: Сделал что-то подобное, спасибо!